# jquery: How can I copy elements after another?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add the contents of one element after the contents of another.  The code below will successfully *move* the element.  What I want/need to do is just place an exact copy of the element to the location?

```
$('#row' + after_index).after($('#availablesongs'));
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#row' + after_index).after($('#availablesongs').clone());
```

Comment: @Mike just be careful when cloning form elements. Browsers handle cloning of elements differently. File/Password - doesn't copy the value. Select doesn't copy selected options in all browsers. Etc.

Comment: Thanks Phill.  Any alt suggestions?  I was originally thinking some kind of ajax and spitting out the form elements I need attached and using after() alone.